# Truecrypt crashes, recover container

Tags: truecrypt

This morning I found out that my 30gb truecrypt container cannot be accessed.
When I select the file and enter the password, Truecrypt freezes for almost 2 minutes.
I cannot open the encrypted volume with explorer, I can only mount and unmount the volume (with 2-3 minutes freeze).

I've tried to recover my data with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), but it freezes too.

Is there any other application I can use to open truecrypt containers and access my files?

Thanks in advance for your help.

System:
Windows7,64bit

Comment: Oh dear. I hope this isn't your only copy. I don't think TrueCrypt has internal redundancy.

Comment: Yes, sadly its my only copy.